# What Do I Need to Change in My Script to Add Column A to Column B Returning the Answer in Column B Each Time I Hit My Button to Add Them?

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm brand new to java & scripting in Google Sheets & this is my first question on here, so any etiquette tips are appreciated.

I have been learning so much from this site, but I've been stuck on this simple error for weeks now & finally just have to ask since I can't find a solution anywhere.

**EDIT to Hopefully be More Clear**

I have a sheet with pricing in column "U" with formulas in columns "V" & "W" that change according to the value in "U". I created a button & attached a script that I would like for it to add the value of each cell in V to the value in W of the same row, for one iteration each time I select the button, & returning the new values in the same cell of column W.

[Example Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYXlt.png)

I've tried a lot of script variations that all returned different results, but none just simply adding these two columns together. Below is what I've patched together that almost does exactly what I need, but it needs a tweak somewhere & I can't figure it out.

```
function testPlus10(){
  var colV = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("V2:V100").getValue();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("W2:W100");
  var cellValues = cell.getValues().map(function(row) {return [row[0] + colV]});
  cell.setValues(cellValues);
}
```

Instead of adding the value in (From the example above) V2 to W2, V3 to W3, & so on down the column, it only adds the value of V2 to every cell in W.  Meaning that from the example: my current script returns values of V2+W2 in W2, V2+W3 in W3, V2+W4 in W4, instead of V2+W2 in W2, V3+W3 in W3, V4+W4 in W4, ect... It adds a $1 to every cell in W.

Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: @Cooper, sorry for the confusion.  In my example, the first cell is U2 & this is equal to the cost of something.  V2 is a 10% margin of that cost that won't be seen in the final sheet, & W2 is a 40% margin mark up of the cost in U2.  So I just want the script to add the the value in V2 (AKA the 10% margin) to the marked up price in W2.

The script sample I posted did that, but then it added the $1 from V2 to every cell in W meaning V2+W2, V2+W3, V2+W4, instead of V2+W2, V3+W3, V4+W4, & down the rest of the columns.

Comment: It's okay.  I'm glad Rodrigo figured it out.  I honestly don't care about the points.  I was just trying to help you.

Comment: I don't know anything about the points & such, but I appreciate the help.  I didn't want to get into the 100 variations of scripts I tried & how close each of the results were to what I want, so maybe I over simplified it all.  I figured I was just missing some small tweak in my script that I couldn't figure out. While Rodrigo's answer gets the result I'm looking for, it runs pretty slow, but it's also working more than anything I had prior so that is much appreciated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the expected behavior, you can use this code, which is pretty simple and can be used for multiple columns of your choice.

[image]

```
function sumColumns(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var currentRow = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getLastRow(); //Get the last row with value on your sheet data as a whole to only scan rows with values
  for(var x =2; x<=currentRow; x++){ //Loop starts at row 2
    if(spreadsheet.getRange("V"+x).getValue() == ""){ //Checks if V (row# or x) value is null
      Logger.log("Cell V"+x+" is empty"); //Logs the result for review
    }
    else{
      var res = spreadsheet.getRange("V"+x).getValue() + spreadsheet.getRange("W"+x).getValue(); //SUM of V & W values
        spreadsheet.getRange("W"+x).setValue(res); //Replace W value with "res"
    }
  }
}
```